# Probability of drug effectiveness

Tags: probability

Extensive testing has shown that a new drug is effective on 90% of patients. The drug company is interested in the evaluating the probability of the drug’s effectiveness for a group of 25 randomly selected patients.

Of the 25 patients administered the drug, what is the probability that it is effective for 23 or fewer patients (ie. effective for 23 or 22 or 21 or … or 2 or 1 or none)?

(a) 0.1994

(b) 0.2712

(c) 0.2659

(d) 0.9282

(e) 0.7288

How do I calculate this?

Answer (score 0):

$$
p(n=24)=25*0.9^{24}*0.1
$$
$$
p(n=25) = 0.9^{25}
$$
so 
$$
p(n<=23)=1-p(n=24)-p(n=25)=0.7288
$$